# declaring namespace to effect script in xamarin.forms (Iphone X)

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use an effect for iphone X like this:

https://xamarinhelp.com/safeareainsets-xamarin-forms-ios/

I have this script in my IOS project, inside my folder named Effects

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using neoFly_Montana.iOS;
using neoFly_Montana.iOS.Effects;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(SafeAreaPaddingEffect), 
nameof(SafeAreaPaddingEffect))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.iOS.Effects
{

public class SafeAreaPaddingEffect : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlatformEffect
{
    Thickness _padding;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (Element is Layout element)
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                _padding = element.Padding;
                var insets = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].SafeAreaInsets; // Can't use KeyWindow this early
                if (insets.Top > 0) // We have a notch
                {
                    element.Padding = new Thickness(_padding.Left + insets.Left, _padding.Top + insets.Top, _padding.Right + insets.Right, _padding.Bottom);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Uses a default Padding of 20. Could use an property to modify if you wanted.
            element.Padding = new Thickness(_padding.Left, _padding.Top + 20, _padding.Right, _padding.Bottom);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        if (Element is Layout element)
        {
            element.Padding = _padding;
        }
    }
}
}
```

in my xaml I putted it:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.LayoutScripts"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.MenuView"
         Title="Menu"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"            
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"                 
         xmlns:effect="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Effects">

<Grid>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill" Source="menubackground.jpg"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->

        <!--Top Grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0">

            <Image Source="topmenu.png" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--sair e user info-->
                <Grid RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.Margin>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                                 iOS="0,20,0,0"/>
                    </Grid.Margin>

                    <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->

                    <!--sair button-->
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <StackLayout.Effects>
                            <effect:SafeAreaPaddingEffect />
                        </StackLayout.Effects>
```

the error is:

> Type effect:SafeAreaPaddingEffect not found in xmlns

I created this in my pcl project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Effects
{
public class SafeAreaPaddingEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public SafeAreaPaddingEffect() : base("MyCompany.SafeAreaPaddingEffect")
    {
    }
}
}
```

the padding not work in Iphone X.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: your SafeAreaPaddingEffect class is not marked as public

Comment: Now it's public and the error has been there yet :(

Comment: is the effect defined in the same project, or a different project?

Comment: I defined it in the .iOS project and the view is in the portable project...
Idk if it is a problem...maybe...

Comment: When the resource is provided by a different project it needs to be declared including the `assembly` property, like you did with the `ffimageloading` namespace, for example. But I couldn't figure out why are you creating a dependency on your portable class to a specific platform project. I don't think it will work really

Comment: hmmmmmm...maybe, I need to create an effect for each platform...maybe...I am not sure about how it works...

Comment: I think you're on the right way. But I believe that your effect class definition should be in the shared project and the renderer of it on the platform specific project. [This article can lead you the way](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/creating/)

Comment: It worked, friend!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked using this in the pcl project

```
public class SafeAreaPaddingEffect : RoutingEffect
{
   public SafeAreaPaddingEffect() : base("MyCompany.SafeAreaPaddingEffect")
  {
  }
}
```